# File History keeps backing up entire user profile

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro and noticed that File History, which previously had been configured to only back up my OneDrive folder, now backs up my entire user profile (except hidden folders like AppData). This is undesirable because it includes several large folders that I either back up manually (e.g. VMs) or don't need to back up at all (e.g. Downloads).

However, I cannot seem to configure File History to exclude those folders, to make it behave the way it did previously in Windows 8.1. Here's what I've tried:

1. I tried changing the list of folders to back up in the classic control panel (under "System and Security" → "File History"). I seem to recall that option was there in Windows 8.1, but it's not in Windows 10. It simply says it copies files from "Libraries, Desktop, Contacts, Favourites and OneDrive (only files available offline)", with no visible way to change it.
2. Still in the classic control panel, I tried adding all folders in my user profile to the list of excluded folders. This doesn't work - if I hit "Save changes", then go back to the list of excluded folders, the ones I just added simply aren't there.
3. I tried the same things in the new Settings app (under "Update & security" → "Backup") - removing the undesirable folders from "Back up these folders" or adding them to "Exclude these folders". While it seems to work at first, both lists magically reset as soon as File History starts backing up files.
4. I tried manually editing the configuration files, both at the File History target location as well as in %LocalAppData%, but those changes also reset.

How can I fix this? Is there any other place that the configuration files are cached? Or is File History in Windows 10 hard-coded to back up the entire user profile folder?

I've searched online, but haven't found any solutions (at least not any that are applicable to Windows 10), only a few reports of others having the same issue.